# Achieving single-responsibility principle with python abstract classes

Tags: python, oop, single-responsibility-principle, pyright

I want to separate the DB models from the actual classes. But i need two static functions for fetching data from the DB regardless of the subclass type. the implementation for both functions are the same across all DB models.

`pyright` showing an error that `cls` inside `get()` and `get_all()` functions doesn't have a `db` property.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractstaticmethod


class DogsDB:
    lists = ["DOG1", "DOG2", "DOG3"]

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        return cls.lists[id]


class CatsDB:
    lists = ["CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT3"]

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        return cls.lists[id]


class Animal(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @abstractstaticmethod
    def save(m):
        pass

    @abstractstaticmethod
    def _from_model(obj):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        obj = cls.db.get(id)
        return cls._from_model(obj)

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        objs = cls.db.lists

        lists = []
        for obj in objs:
            e = cls._from_model(obj)
            lists.append(e)
        return lists

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class DogSound:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def sound(self):
        print(self.name, ": DOG SOUND!!")


class Dog(Animal, DogSound):
    db = DogsDB

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
        self.age = age

    @staticmethod
    def save(m):
        print(m)

    @staticmethod
    def _from_model(obj):
        return Dog(obj, 4)


class Cat(Animal):
    db = CatsDB

    def __init__(self,  name, age):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.age = age

    @staticmethod
    def save(m):
        print(m)

    @staticmethod
    def _from_model(obj):
        return Cat(obj, 4)


print(Cat.get(1))
print(Dog.get(1))
print(Cat.get_all())
print(Dog.get_all())
Dog.get(1).sound()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot duplicate your first error.

Your second issue is a result of method `sound` implicitly returning `None` since it has no return statement and you have `print(Dog.get(1).sound())`, which will print out the return value from that method. You either want to change this to just `Dog.get(1).sound()` or modify the `sound` method to return what it is currently being printed and remove the `print` statement (my choice).

As an aside, I found this class structure a bit difficult to follow. Why do you need a separate `DogSound` class with a `name` attribute which should belong to `Animal`? Also, it seems to me that `age` could/should be an attribute of `Animal` since both cats and dogs have an age.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractstaticmethod


class DogsDB:
    lists = ["DOG1", "DOG2", "DOG3"]

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        return cls.lists[id]


class CatsDB:
    lists = ["CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT3"]

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        return cls.lists[id]


class Animal(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @abstractstaticmethod
    def save(m):
        pass

    @abstractstaticmethod
    def _from_model(obj):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        obj = cls.db.get(id)
        return cls._from_model(obj)

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        objs = cls.db.lists

        lists = []
        for obj in objs:
            e = cls._from_model(obj)
            lists.append(e)
        return lists

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Dog(Animal):
    db = DogsDB

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name, age)

    def sound(self):
        return f"{self.name}: DOG SOUND!!"

    @staticmethod
    def save(m):
        print(m)

    @staticmethod
    def _from_model(obj):
        return Dog(obj, 4)


class Cat(Animal):
    db = CatsDB

    def __init__(self,  name, age):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.age = age

    @staticmethod
    def save(m):
        print(m)

    @staticmethod
    def _from_model(obj):
        return Cat(obj, 4)


print(Cat.get(1))
print(Dog.get(1))
print(Cat.get_all())
print(Dog.get_all())
print(Dog.get(1).sound())
```

Prints:

```None
CAT2
DOG2
[CAT1, CAT2, CAT3]
[DOG1, DOG2, DOG3]
DOG2: DOG SOUND!!
```

If for some reason you want `DogSound` to be a separate class, then there is no need for the `name` attribute to be duplicated:

```py
...
class DogSound: # A "Mixin" class
    def sound(self):
        return f"{self.name}: DOG SOUND!!"


class Dog(Animal, DogSound):
    db = DogsDB

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name, age)

    @staticmethod
    def save(m):
        print(m)

    @staticmethod
    def _from_model(obj):
        return Dog(obj, 4)
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i changed the implementation to use mixin instead.